# Rest apis for firmware update for iot hub devices

Tags: java, azure, azure-iot-hub

Is it possible to do an over the air(OTA) firmware update, using REST APIs, for the devices registered in azure IOT hub? If so, can someone share the API urls and the required headers. In the azure documentation, I was only able to find the CLI method for firmware update. So please do help, if anyone is aware of the REST APIs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are referring to this doc - [Tutorial: Implement a device firmware update process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/tutorial-firmware-update) - please understand that this is an **example** on how to monitor the firmware update process remotely through a back-end application connected to your hub.

- See [Azure IoT Hub Service REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/#service)

[image]

As most of the OTA process is an exchange of both desired and reported properties of your [device Twin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-device-twins) , the REST API definition above should get you started.

Reference:

- [Digital Twin - Get Digital Twin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/service/digitaltwin/getdigitaltwin)
- [Digital Twin - Update Digital Twin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/service/digitaltwin/updatedigitaltwin)

Comment: @Rakesh S did my response answered your question? Please mark it as answer or share with us further questions. Thanks!